# SilverStripe 3.1 - Wrong $BaseDir after porting to XAMPP

Tags: forms, silverstripe

after porting my fully working SS3.1 Page from my Webserver `http://mydomain.de` to my locally installed XAMPP `http://intranet/silverstripe` I've got the problem that the Base Directory is now wrong in SS. It's the old one from the webserver `/` but it need to be `/silverstripe`

I already changed it in the .htaccess so that mod_rewrite works but $BaseDir returns `/` and if I try to use the SS Sitesearch than I get redirected to `home/SearchForm?Search=` instead of `silverstripe/home/SearchForm?Search=` after submitting the form.

Can someone please help me to fix this problem.

Thank you in advance

**EDIT:**
I just call $SiteSearch in my Template.
But the function is modified in my Page.php to search also through a dataobject.

```
public function results($data, $form){
    $results = $form->getResults();

    $query = htmlspecialchars($data['Search'], ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
    $objects = ListingObject::get()->where("MATCH (Title, Link, Company, Category) AGAINST ('$query' IN BOOLEAN MODE)");      
    $results->merge($objects);

    $data['Results'] = $results;                  
    $data['Title'] = _t('SearchForm.SearchResults', 'Search Results'); 
    $data['Query'] = $query;

    return $this->customise($data)->renderWith(array('Page_results','Page')); 
}
```

without this code it also doesn't work

**SOLUTION:**
I'm sry. I found the Problem. I didn't call $SiteSearch, because when I created the Page, I had to edit the form, so I hardcoded it... because of that, the submitted url is wrong now. I'm so sorry!

Comment: Can you share your site search template code? Do you just call $SiteSearch, or do you have some custom template for this?

Comment: Hi, please have a look at my updated question. I added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to set an alternate base url in the SS config. Add this to your `config.yml`:

```
Director:
  alternate_base_url: '/silverstripe'
```

Comment: hi thanks, that solves the wrong redirect after logging in.
But the problem with the site search still exists. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`$BaseDir` should be [`$BaseHref`](http://doc.silverstripe.com/framework/en/topics/page-type-templates#basehref) in your template.

Comment: ah you're right thank you! But this do not solve the sitesearch problem